# Как исправить неправильную кодировку в переменной среды?

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, кодировка, environment-variables

Пытаюсь подключиться к `Docker` через `IDEA`, рабочая система `Windows 8.1`. При подключении к виртуальной машине возникает ошибка:

[image: Ошибка при подключении к ВМ]

> com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Enabled TLS verification (DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1) but certificate path (DOCKER_CERT_PATH) 'C:\Users\Р•РІРіРµРЅРёР№\.docker\machine\machines\default' doesn't exist.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причина ошибки выясняется довольно просто. В переменных среды указано следующее:

> DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\Евгений\.docker\machine\machines\default

Слово `Евгений` в пути по-видимому интерпретируется в неправильной кодировке *(а конкретно в windows-1251)*, отсюда и все проблемы. Конечно, в голову приходят два самых простых решения:

1. Поместить папку с сертификатами по другому пути *(без кириллицы)*.
2. Переименовать пользователя системы.

Есть ли какой-то другой путь? Как можно заставить `IDEA` затягивать переменные окружения в кодировке `UTF-8`?

**UPD (09.05.22):** размещение папки с сертификатами по другому пути ничего не даёт. Потому что, когда я изменяю путь в переменных среды, а потом запускаю ВМ, то путь устанавливается обратно на изначальный. По-видимому, это делает Oracle VM, и я не понимаю, как отключить это поведение. Также я попытался изменить переменную среды DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY на 0, чтобы отключить проверку сертификата вообще, но эта переменная также устанавливается на 1 при запуске ВМ.

Comment: Ну вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, зачем вам лишние проблемы

Comment: @PerfectVoyage мм, там тоже проблем много. Попробовал установить папку в другое место и поменять переменную среды, чтобы она указывала на новое местоположение сертификата, но переменная меняется обратно при запуске вм. Походу её нельзя так просто поменять. Менять имя пользователя довольно муторно - там другие настройки полетят

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, переименовав пользователя и его папку.

В `Windows 8.1` это делается довольно сложно, в результате чуть не убил систему. Но сейчас всё работает, `Docker` запускается, `IDEA` подключается.

У меня существовал ещё один вариант: поменять переменную среды в докер-машине, однако я не нашёл способа этого сделать. У следующей команды:

> docker-machine env

я не нашёл опций, которые позволяют именно установить переменную среды.